# Why is this <Text> component pushed so far below this react-native-draggable-flatlist?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I would like to have this Text component immediately follow the react-native-draggable-flatlist (https://github.com/computerjazz/react-native-draggable-flatlist). Seems like there is still some overflow affecting surrounding components despite setting flexGrow.

### Code

https://snack.expo.io/@nicksinai/react-native-draggable-flatlist-flow-issue

### Error

[image]

Comment: it looks like that `DraggableFlatList` is taking the whole space and ignoring any `height` prop you can pass it in `style` or `contentContainerStyle`. So try wrapping it in a `View` and giving that `View` a fixed height

Comment: @Milore that works. Ideally, I'd like to keep the add activity touchable right below the list. I could probably calculate the required height.

Comment: <View style={{ height: data.length * ITEM_HEIGHT }}> works alright

Comment: That could be a way, but it depends on your goals: what if the number of elements makes the View higher then the window? I think the "add activity" button would be pushed at the very bottom of the list, out of the window.

Comment: You could still give it a maxHeight: windowHeight - (button height + any other element height), but... up to you

Comment: Yeah it did push it out the window, I'm trying wrapping in a safe area view and assigning flex1 to it and the screen. Sticks the add activity button at the bottom, but everything else works well.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to wrap the react-native-draggable-flatlist in a

https://snack.expo.io/@nicksinai/react-native-draggable-flatlist-flow-solution

Comment: Gives this error though: "VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead."